# angular2 , and my service announcement execute multiple times

Tags: angular

I dont get it!

This is what I want ot do.  I run a model on the api server and takes about 5-10 mins to run.  So I poll the api server for when its done then I wil add code to trigger a snackbar that model is complete.

1) In my app component, I subscribe to a service that will listen for announcements from other components 
    app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.polllingCallService()
}

  polllingCallService(){
    this.polling_sub = this.pollingService.pollingAnnounced$.subscribe(
      polling => {
        this.polling = polling;
        console.log('WOWWWWWWWWW')
        if (this.polling){
          this.pollingRemoteService(polling)
        } else{
          console.log('polling as nothing to do...')
        }
      });
  } //end
```

From another component, I send an announcement

```
this.pollingService.announcePolling({'model_id':gg,'is_output':false});
```

Well it works but its called twice per the logs:

```
WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "aaaaa", is_output: false}
WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "aaaaa", is_output: false}
```

Also the below is executed twice:

```
this.pollingRemoteService(polling)
```

Another time it was this many times:

```
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
app.component.ts:132 WOWWWWWWWWW {model_id: "bbbbbb", is_output: false}
```

And this is thus executed many times:

```
  this.pollingRemoteService(polling)
```

So what happens is I get the api server twice or more in my polling service when it should be once.

Why does this happen?

Here is my polling service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class PollingService {

  constructor() { }

  private pollingAnnouncedSource = new Subject<object>();
  // Observable string streams
  pollingAnnounced$ = this.pollingAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  // Service message commands
  announcePolling(polling: object) {
    this.pollingAnnouncedSource.next(polling);
  }

}
```

Here is the main code that is executed FYI on the app.component.ts:

```
isEmpty(obj) {
    console.log('yo dude',obj)
    //https://coderwall.com/p/_g3x9q/how-to-check-if-javascript-object-is-empty
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  pollingRemoteService(polling){

    let url = this.getEndpointPollingUrl(this.polling_endpoint)
    var result = Observable.interval(5000)
                           .switchMap(() => this._authHttp.get(url + '/' + polling['model_id']))
                           .map(res => res.json())
                           .takeWhile(models => this.isEmpty(models) == false);

    this.af_poll = result.subscribe(
      polldata  => {
        //this.polldata = polldata;
        //console.log('really?',polldata)
        //this.pollingComplete()
      },
      error => {
        let error_json = JSON.parse(error.text())
        console.log('error',error_json) 
      }
    );
    //console.log('this.af_poll',this.af_poll)


  }
```

Comment: I added more code and the complete objective of what I want to do.  Code works and will stop executing when condition is met due to the takeWhile but with multiple subscriptions

Comment: you have a memory leak somewhere, not unsubscribing appropriately, you seem to be saving the subscription, are you calling unsubscribe on it correctly?

Comment: Are you able to condense this down into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have a memory leak. Manually generated subscriptions often need to be manually cleaned up. Your `polling_sub` subscription is never cleaned up and unsubscribed from in your given code.

You don't mention any `unsubscribe` call for the subscription generated in the `polllingCallService()` method. If you haven't already, add this method to that component:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.polling_sub.unsubscribe();
}
```